# tracking click to call phone calls in minisite on mobile- events tracking in google analytics

Tags: events, tracking

I am trying to track in google analytics clicks from phone calls on mobile (Click to call calls) in minisite on the site and i add a code in page after the phone number like this:

In addition i defined a goal in google analytics that include the parameters:

Category - Equals to - Call tracking
Action - Equals to - Click to call
Label - Equals to- Phone in mobile
Value - I left the field blank

now the minisite is running but i dont see conversions or events in google analytics even that i know that people click on the phone number from mobile.
Am I doing something wrong or need to change something in the code or in the definition of the goal in order to start getting date of the clicks?

Comment: You might want to try google first, really, the first hit: http://gatipoftheday.com/track-mobile-click-to-call-actions-as-google-analytics-events/

Comment: they dont talk about universal code and this is what Relevant for me.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your code?

Comment: this is my code <a href="tel:0000000000" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Call tracking', 'Click to call', 'Phone in mobile');">